# proper use of count(*) with group by function

Tags: sql

In sql can you use a GROUP BY function with a column like country? (which would be a char/varchar)

```
SELECT country, population, COUNT(*) AS count_cities
FROM list_of_cities
GROUP BY country;
```

What would be a better way to write this?

Comment: "What would be a better way to write this" - But what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to understand use of count(*) vs. count(column_name) and figure out how one is different vs. others. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT country, SUM(population) AS country_population, COUNT(*) AS count_cities 
FROM list_of_cities 
GROUP BY country;
```